# Mounting /opt on docker containers on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-volume

I know that there are very similar questions around, but I could not find the answer that worked for me.

I'm having issues with docker volumes on MacOS:
`docker run --rm -it -v /opt/docker/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql -p 3333:3306 mysql:8.0.18`

As you can see, my volume is being mounted from /opt/docker/mysql directory, which is not on the Docker's default settings, but I've added it:

[image: Docker Settings]

Still, when I try to run that docker container, I get and error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: EOF.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Can someone please point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you checked your directory permissions?

Comment: Please check this https://gist.github.com/codeinthehole/7ea69f8a21c67cc07293

Comment: Did you test any other folder?

Comment: Permissions are correct. Other folders work, but I'd really like to understand what is happening.
Will check on that link.

Comment: On Linux. Some distros put docker under a MAC (apparmor, selinux, etc) that limits the volumes to only /home